# Cannot load facet Django in Pycharm community version, but no error in professional version

Tags: django, pycharm

I started learning Django by building a simple project with Pycharm community version first, then in the middle of the development, I switched to the professional version. After the trial version expired, I moved back to the community version.

Now when I am using the community version, Pycharm shows event error:

> Error Loading Project: Cannot load facet Django

If I try the professional version, it's successfully loaded.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Professional version adds many tools and plugins, and among those the one for Django. It's no surprise that community version doesn't allow you to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Click "Details..." in the warning popup and answer "Yes" to the suggestion to ignore the facet or manually remove `<facet type="django" name="Django">` node and all it's children from `.idea/<project_name>.iml` stored in your project root.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is a big deal, Community edition simply doesn't support Django so it complains about an unknown setting entries. You can always drop the entire `.idea/` and reopen the project to restore defaults.